# How to make a persistent list of options in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an app related to a TTRPG (Pathfinder 2e, specifically, in case you wanted to know). This is my first foray into Swift and iOS development, and I'm struggling to understand the appropriate way to do what I want.

In a TTRPG, you have your "Ability Scores" - Strength (STR), Dexterity (Dex), Constitution (CON), Wisdom (WIS), Intelligence (INT), and Charisma (CON).

I'd like to be able to make a struct (I think? Maybe this should be a class?) that looks something like this:

```
struct AbilityScores {
    var shortName: String //i.e. STR
    var longName: String //i.e. Strength
    var description: String //i.e. "Strength is used for XYZ and PDQ" 
};
```

`AbilityScores` will always have exactly those six values. My instincts tell me that I should be using an `enum` for this, but I'm not exactly sure how to make the enum function correctly.

I can do something like

```
struct abilityScore {
    var short: String
    var long: String
    var description: String
    
    init (short: String, long: String, desc: String){
        self.short = short
        self.long = long
        self.description = desc
    }
}
    
enum AbilityScores {
    case STR
    case DEX
    case CON
    case INT
    case WIS
    case CHA
    
    func GetAbilityScore() -> abilityScore {
        switch self {
        case .STR:
            return abilityScore(short: "STR", long: "Strength", desc: "Strength Description")
        case .DEX:
            return abilityScore(short: "DEX", long: "Dexterity", desc: "Dex Description")
        case .CON:
            return abilityScore(short: "CON", long: "Constitution", desc: "Con Description")
        case .INT:
            return abilityScore(short: "INT", long: "Intelligence", desc: "Int Description")
        case .WIS:
            return abilityScore(short: "WIS", long: "Wisdom", desc: "Wisdom Description")
        case .CHA:
            return abilityScore(short: "CHA", long: "Charisma", desc: "CHA description")
        };
        
        
    }
}
```

Then, for example, I can have something that looks like this in another spot:

```
struct Background {
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var allowedAbilityBoosts: [abilityScore] = [AbilityScores.CON.GetAbilityScore(), AbilityScores.DEX.GetAbilityScore()]
}
```

and just call `GetAbilityScore()` wherever I want it.

Is this the correct approach?

What about a scenario (like for Background) where instead of having 6 items, I have up to a couple hundred? Is there a better way to instantiate the list of all the items? I'm happy to read documentation on this, but I don't know where to even start.

Would it be appropriate to use an internal SQLite database (if that's even a thing in iOS development) to store the data? Or am I going to be stuck in enum purgatory?

Comment: Lookup UserDefaults. No need for enums. Also, there is a sqlite wrapper called SwiftData, but save that for later.

Comment: I disagree. Watch WWDC videos or read some articles on SwiftData.  It hides a lot of complexity and will probably be easier to use than trying to misuse UserDefaults as an object Store. I probably wouldn't use an enum though. Just have discrete properties for each ability score.

Comment: After reading about UserDefaults a bit, I don't think that's the appropriate approach here at all -- this should be more like a database table that can only be read from by the user, and not modified. It will be consistent across all installations of the app and not something they're editing. The "Background" will be something like "Criminal" or "Bartender", which will have 1-2 AbilityScores in the allowedAbilityBoost field--also stored data and not user input or settings.